# Post form data to rest resource in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post form data as a request body to a rest service using angularJS but I cannot get it to hit the resource. Please help if you can..

I have a service like this ...

```
angular.
  module('core.search').
  factory('Search', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:8888/PROJECT/rest/search, {}, {
          query: {
              method: 'POST',
              isArray: true
          }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

A component like this...

```
angular.
  module('vehicleSearch').
  component('vehicleSearch', {
    templateUrl: 'vehicle-search/vehicle-search.template.html',
    controller: ['Search',
      function VehicleSearchController(Search) {
        this.vehicles = [];
        this.searchVehicles = function(vehicleSearchForm) {
            this.vehicles = Search.query([], JSON.stringify(vehicleSearchForm));
        };
      }
    ]
  });
```

and a template like this ...

```
<div>
<h4>Vehicle Search</h4>
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.searchVehicles(vehicleSearchForm)">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="vrm" >VRM: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vrm" name="vrm" ng-model="vehicleSearchForm.vrm" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="type" name="type" ng-model="vehicleSearchForm.type" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="search"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>VRM</td>
            <td>Make</td>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td>Colour</td>
            <td>Date Registered</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in $ctrl.vehicles">
            <td>{{vehicle.vrm}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle.make}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle.model}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle.colour}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle.dateFirstReg}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I know the resource is returning data as I can call it through my testing tool with a request body with media type application/json like ..
{"type" : "vehicleSearchRequest", "searchReason" : "01", "vrm" : "ABC123"}

I thought maybe I needed to specify what media type the body would be but the default appears to be the same so am at a loss. When I try this in angular I can see the request is hitting the server as is authenticated but then does nothing so believe it is something to do with the request body. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was in fact due to my rest resources being on a different domain. The browser doesn't allow this for security reasons. The error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. For anybody who makes same mistake see: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.[website].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)